# Can I limit the width of element relative to its parent?

Tags: html, css, liquid-layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>KPMG HTML5 TEST</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="m5.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <header class="header">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </header>
    <div class="nav">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_left">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_right">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>testing for responsivenedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsssssssssssssSSSSSSSSss</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a website with responsive web design. Here's my CSS file.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
    width:67.625%;
    position: relative;
}
.upper_left,.left{
    float:left;
}
.upper_right,.center, .right{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 1.663586%;  /*18px*/
}

.upper_left{
    width:74.5841%;
}
.upper_right{
    width:23.752311%;
}
.left{
    width:23.752311%;
}
.center{
    width:49.168207%;
}
.right{
    width:23.752311%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Since I want to create a website with width 67.625%only (1082px out of 1600), I want paragraph on div right to move to next line when it exceeds the width 23.752% of content(67.652% of the monitor). I tried to make the position of content class and right class relative but it does not work. Is there any way this could be solved?

Comment: There is no need for relative position on the .right class. I think you are having different problem without knowing it (word-break) but cannot tell without a fiddle. Post a fiddle and people will be ahppy to help

Comment: I tried having relative on .right and without relative on .right. It doesn't matter. Here's the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/001rmwjc/4/ Hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add word-break: break-all; to the .right class.

Like this:

```css
 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
background:#eee;
    width:67.625%;
    position: relative;
}
.upper_left,.left{
    float:left;
 background:#ddd;
}
.upper_right,.center, .right{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 1.663586%;  /*18px*/
 background:#ccc;
}

.upper_left{
    width:74.5841%;
}
.upper_right{
    width:23.752311%;
}
.left{
    width:23.752311%;
}
.center{
    width:49.168207%;
}
.right{
    width:23.752311%;
    position: relative;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>KPMG HTML5 TEST</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <header class="header">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </header>
    <div class="nav">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_left">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_right">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>testing for responsivenedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsssssssssssssSSSSSSSSss</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>testing for responsiveness</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem. It's only about the length of that but only the issue of width of divs.

Answer (score 0):

What you would like is **very simple**. First off lets say you would like it to move to the next line of text if it is perhaps 50% of the parent's width. You would use the property `max-width` in CSS. Here is an example:

```
HTML
----------
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        This text will eventually overflow.
    </div>
</div>

CSS
----------
#parent {
     width: 500px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: red;
}
#child {
     max-width: 50%; /* 50% is the width used for the example */
}
```

So as you can see `max-width` can achieve this for you.
If you would like I posted a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de4j760q/) for you.

Comment: Actually I want left center and right to align and when the content on the right class exceeds 23.752311% of content class, it moves to the next line. I tried to set max-width but it didn't work. Would be nice if you could post JSFiddle for me.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if it is possible to do that with just simply CSS. If you would only like that event to happen when the content exceeds the parent then I am pretty sure you would need javascript. Here would be the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/de4j760q/2/) to style that though :)

Comment: Thank you. It's only about the length of that word.

Comment: Hmm, more thinking and I have a question. Do you mean if for example you have the word "fsdafdafdsafsafdsa" and it overflows the div because the word is too long? If so I know how to fix that! :)

Comment: yes it is. Actually I got the answer from Yury already. Thank you so much :)